# Google Cloud Video Intelligence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

Below it says in Google Cloud documentation :

Annotating a video using Shot Change detection
This tutorial walks you through a basic Video API application, using a SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION request. A SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION request provides the annotation results:

List of all shots that occur within the video, with the following code :

```
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.Feature.SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION]
operation = video_client.annotate_video(
    request={"features": features, "input_uri": path}
)
print("\nProcessing video for shot change annotations:")

result = operation.result(timeout=120)
print("\nFinished processing.")
```

But it doesn't mention about the detection of the scene's at the time of shot change.

How can I also get Scene Detection with Google Cloud Video Intelligence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence#benefits) "Video Intelligence API automatically recognizes more than 20,000 objects, places, and actions in stored and streaming video. It also distinguishes scene changes and extracts rich metadata at the video, shot, or frame level", so, the answer of your question is yes, the API has scene detection.

Comment: Ok, let's tranform the question then, how can I also get Scene Detection with GCP Video Intelligence ?